# Where's 'Create New Preflight Fixup', in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Please see the screenshots beneath. 1. Is the left screenshot wrong, from [this Mar 31 2017 article](http://khkonsulting.com/2017/03/remove-content-from-pdf-files-using-acrobats-preflight/)?

[image]

2. Are Adobe's different [instructions](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/acrobat/using/correcting-problem-areas-preflight-tool.html) beneath correct? They unhelpfully didn't include screenshots.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to fixups first. You are now searching in preflight (see screenshot). 
[image]